# Move object with finger on x-axis 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a question: How can I moce a object on the x-axis with my finger on th smartphone? In the internet I can only find solutions for 2d but non for 3d projects.

I have tried this code, but it is really jerky:

```
 void FixedUpdate()
     {
         if (Input.touchCount == 1) {
              touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
 
              if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
                  transform.position = new Vector3(
                      transform.position.x + touch.deltaPosition.x * speedModifier,
                      transform.position.y,
                      transform.position.z
                  );
              }
          }
          transform.position = new Vector3(
              transform.position.x, 
              transform.position.y, 
              transform.position.z + (speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime)
              );
     }
```

The real question is, how can I make this code, that it works smoothly, because it is really unsmoothly at the moment?

Comment: Please edit your question, show what you tried and what it is not working and your project. Don't ask for code and nothing else

Comment: Please note that StackOverflow is not for asking "Please someone implement XY for me" or "Someone give my a link/tutorial for XY" but rather about "Please someone help me with this specific issue I encountered while implementing this specific code I added to my question where I try to achieve XY but instead ZZ happens". Please make sure to take the  [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also refer to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @derHugo thank you for you wuick response! Sorry for the mistacke I´m pretty new to this topc :( but now I have added the code I tried. Hopefully you can tell me why the code doesn´t work smoothly.

Comment: @Leoverload I have now added the code I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move the player where you are pressing you can use this code that is simpler than yours:

```
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                transform.position = new Vector3(
                   transform.position.x,
                   transform.position.y,
                   transform.position.z + touch.deltaPosition.x * speed);
}
}
```

It is very customizable, in this case, for example, I am moving the player along the **z-axis** , like in your example, but it depends on the position of the finger from **left to right**.

You can easily change the last part of the code in the way you prefer, for example:

```
transform.position = new Vector3(
                   transform.position.x + touch.deltaPosition.x * speed,
                   transform.position.y + touch.deltaPosition.y * speed,
                   transform.position.z);
```

In this way, it will go up and down and left and right, based on the point you press and it could be useful for a game in 2d view. In 3D keep in mind that if you press up you want to move on the **z axis** most of the time so my first code is working well because I am changing z position on the x touch.